# Know when a different class is exited

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently coding a project Java in eclipse which has two classes. The first class (open) I use to send a specific string to my second class (viewer) and then run my second class. The second class (viewer) I have imported into my program in the form of a jar file. I have done it this way as class viewer is a pdf viewer that i created using apache PDFBox and class open sends the file to the viewer to use, but the file will be different depending on many conditions (that are not relevant) in class open. The point is that class open needs to be separate from class viewer and can not simply be two different methods in one class. I would like to know if there is a way for class open to know when class viewer has been closed, as currently I am using a while loop, which just eats up memory and is very inefficient. The code I have does currently work, but I feel there is a better way, perhaps using listeners. This is the code for closing class viewer:

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent; 
//and import swing components ect

Public class viewer extends javax.swing.JFrame
implements KeyListener,
ActionListener{
    private javax.swing.JButton zoomIn;
    private javax.swing.JButton zoomOut;
    //and a bunch more swing components
    public static boolean closed = false;
    public static String fileName = "";
    public viewer()
    {
    }

private void initComponents() throws IOException
{
  addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)
        {
            exitApplication();
        }
    });
}

private void exitMenuItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
    if( document != null )
    {
        try
        {
            document.close();
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    closed = true;
    System.exit(0);
}
public static void main(String filename) throws Exception
{
    fileName = filename;
    viewer mainViewer = new viewer();
    String[] splittedStr = fileName.split("/");
    BASETITLE = splittedStr[splittedStr.length - 1];
    if (fileName != null)
    {
        mainViewer.openPDFFile(fileName);
    }
    mainViewer.setVisible(true);
}
```

This is my code from class open:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = "C:/Files/Test.pdf";
    viewer.main(fileName);
    while(viewer.closed == false)
    {
        if(viewer.closed == true)
        {
            System.out.print("The Viewer Has Been Closed");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know when it is closed so I can delete the file on the local drive. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `viewer.closed` What is viewer? Does it extend or are any of it's accessible fields a `JFrame`?

Comment: "I feel there is a better way, perhaps using listeners." You have answered your own question.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm pretty sure he could remove everything after `viewer.main(fileName);` and it would still work.

Comment: Actually you don't need `closed = true;` after `System.exit(0);`. That code is unreachable.

Comment: Your code and question is kinda confusing. Normally you dont send messages form classes, you have objects. And classes dont "close". You call methods; they run; and at some point they finish. And calling System.exit() ends your whole JVM. In other words: it seems that you have big problems even understanding essential basics of Java. I would suggest to turn back into learning mode; so that you get a better grip on the **concepts** you are using.

Comment: What is `viewer`? I assume this is the "class b" which you mention in the prose of your question. I suggest that you edit your post to keep the names consistent in order to reduce confusion. Also, do you have the source code or API docs for this `viewer` class and its supporting classes?

Comment: I have updated my post so it is a little less confusing. @bradimus is there a link to a resource that gives an example or something more in tune to what I'm looking for that you could direct me to? I don't need full code, just a explanation would be great, I'm fairly new to java

Comment: @vsminkov Yeah that was my bad, I copied my code wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so I actually found an answer to my question and I'll just post it in case someone else had the same problem as me. I added a interface to the open class with the method close as shown:

```
import mainpackage.viewer;
public class Open implements closeInterface{

    public Open() { }
    public static String fileName;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        fileName = "C:/Files/Test.pdf";
        run();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        System.out.print("The Viewer Has Been Closed");

    }

    public static void run() throws Exception
    {
        viewer view = new viewer();
        view.main(fileName);
        view.addListener(new Open());
    }
}
```

This was my code for my interface:

```
package mainpackage;

public interface closeInterface {
    public void close();
}
```

And this was the snipit of code for my Viewer class

```
public class viewer  extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private static closeInterface Closed;
   private void initComponents() throws IOException
  {
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)
        {
            exitApplication();
        }
    });
  }
  private void exitApplication()
  {
    try
    {
        if( document != null )
        {
            document.close();
        }
    }
    catch( IOException io )
    {
        //do nothing because we are closing the application
    }
    Closed.close();
    this.setVisible( false );
    this.dispose();
  }
   public void addListener(closeInterface closed){
    Closed = closed;
  }
}
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Either you pass a callback (e.g. a Runnable) as argument to viewer.main, like viewer.main(fileName, () -> System.out.print("The Viewer Has Been Closed")) and make sure that it is called when the process is done, or you do as you've done except that you sleep your main thread a short time in the while loop, like Thread.sleep(100).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, did you have a website of some form that explains your idea? If so that would be super helpful, as I've been unsuccessful in looking it up so far :)